# Question regarding the prime factors of $2^{35} - 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences, prime-factorization

> Question regarding the prime factors of $2^{35} - 1$

I just wanted to make a few things clear;

1) It is true to state that this cannot be a Mersenne prime (A number of the form $2^r - 1$ where if this is prime then $r$ must be prime, for $r \in \mathbb{Z}$) as r is not prime, as the converse of the definition of a Mersenne prime is not necessarily true.

2) I went about solving it by assuming $\exists$ a prime factor of the form $70x + 1$ this would therefore be for the first option $x = 1$ and hence $71$

(I now know that this is only necessary when trying to prove that a value of $2^r - 1$ is not prime for $r$ prime. - as every prime factor of $2^r - 1$ is of the form $2xr + 1$, and in this case $r = 35$ which is not prime)

Basically I want to show that $2^{35} \equiv 1 $ mod $71$ (Which I showed to be true).

So 71 is a prime factor. I also noticed that $2^5 - 1$ and $2^7 - 1$ are also prime factors equal to 31 and 127 respectively (Does this have something to do with the fact that 5 and 7 are prime factors of 35 - if so what is this fact, or is/should it be trivial).

And the last prime factor I figured out from wolfram - alpha to be equal to $122921$.

I was wondering if there was actually a method to figure out all these prime factors without rigorous number crunching, as I am yet to learn of one yet.

Comment: you get the factors $2^5-1$ and $2^7-1$ for free. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime#About_Mersenne_primes
This should also answer you 1)

Comment: $\forall{d,n\in\mathbb{N}}:d|n\implies2^d-1|2^n-1$.

Comment: The ifactor command of Maple outputs $$ 2^{35}-1=31\cdot 71 \cdot 127 \cdot 122921.$$

Comment: @MichaelStocker Thanks for your reply - is there any way to find all the prime factors of a Mersenne prime? Or is such a method not yet known / impossible.

Comment: There is an adapted P-1-Method used by Gimps: http://www.mersenne.org/various/math.php . Apart from the I don't know of anything better

Comment: how did you assume a prime factor of the form 70x+1?